# why does my function work on it's own but not with sapply?

Tags: r, bioinformatics

I am working on a COVID analysis project. I have a list 'sc' of dataframes for each state, each data frame contains columns for date and incident_cases in that state:

```
sc$Alabama
# A tibble: 489 x 3
# Groups:   state [1]
   state   date       incident_cases
   <chr>   <chr>               <dbl>
 1 Alabama 2020-01-22              0
 2 Alabama 2020-01-23              0
 3 Alabama 2020-01-24              0
 4 Alabama 2020-01-25              0
 5 Alabama 2020-01-26              0
```

I have defined a function to give me COVID's reproductive number:

```
get_r<-function(df){
as.incidence(df$incident_cases,df$date) %>% 
estimate_R(method = 'parametric_si', config=make_config(list(mean_si=5.6,std_si=4.2)))
}
```

This function works perfectly on individual elements of my list 'sc'

```
get_r(sc$Alabama)
```

However, when I use sapply to run the function on every state I get the following error

```
sapply(sc,get_r)
Default config will estimate R on weekly sliding windows.
    To change this change the t_start and t_end arguments. 
Default config will estimate R on weekly sliding windows.
    To change this change the t_start and t_end arguments. 
 Error: At least one (non-NA) date must be provided
```

I have tried reformating the date column as a Date but this didn't change anything. Any thoughts on why I  am getting this error and how I can work around it are greatly appreciated.

Comment: One of your states have no date - NA. Try: `sapply(sc, function(i) table(is.na(i[, "date"])))` see if all states have non-na dates.

Comment: Thank you for this though. When I run this all states come back FALSE, which I believe means there are no missing dates. I also checked this with sum(is.na()) for each state with yeilds 0

Comment: Then my guess would be: somewhere code is trying to convert it to date, and fails, so you get NAs.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't so much of an answer, I just can't fit this recommendation into a comment.

Try the following:

```r
get_r <- function(df){
tryCatch({
  as.incidence(df$incident_cases,df$date) %>% 
    estimate_R(method = 'parametric_si', 
               config=make_config(list(mean_si=5.6,std_si=4.2)))
}, error = function(e) NA)

}
```

With this all errors will become NA's and you will hopefully be able to find which states are issues

```r
results <- lapply(sc, get_r)
vapply(results, identical, FUN.VALUE = logical(1), y = NA) %>%
  which()
```

We probably wont be able to identify what the exact issue is without a reproducible example, but this should at least help you start debugging your data.